# How do you resolve 'hidden imports not found!' warnings in pyinstaller for scipy?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, scikit-learn, pyinstaller

I'm working on using pyinstaller to create an .exe for a python program that uses pandas and sklearn. The pyinstaller process completes and produces the dist folder with the executable as expected. However, when I run the .exe I get module import errors related to sklearn and scipy.

I created a test script (test.py) to test imports, which only imports pandas and sklearn and then prints a success message:

```
import time
import pandas as pd
import sklearn

def main():
  print('hello world!')
  time.sleep(5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

I'm aware of pyinstaller hooks and I was able to resolve the pandas errors by adding a hook to the pyinstaller hooks directory. I added similar hooks for sklearn and scipy it looks like they're running, but in the pyinstaller output I'm getting warnings that 'Hidden import "sklearn.utils.sparsetools._graph_validation" not found!' and similar one for '._graph_tools'.

Here's the hook for scipy (hook-scipy.py):

```
print('loading custome hook for scipy')

from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_submodules
hiddenimports = collect_submodules('scipy')
```

Here's a snapshot of the warnings generated from running pyinstaller

[image]

Here's a snapshot of the error when running test.exe

[image]

I'm working in a virtual environment where pyinstaller, pandas, sklearn, scipy and all dependencies are installed (at least I can get the regular test.py script running in this venv). Using PyInstaller 3.3.1, Python 3.6.4 on Windows 10.10.0.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to go into the hook-scipy.py (or create one) and have it look like this:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_submodules
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files
hiddenimports = collect_submodules('scipy')

datas = collect_data_files('scipy')
```

then go into the hook-sklearn.metrics.cluster.py file and modify it to look like this:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files

hiddenimports = ['sklearn.utils.sparsetools._graph_validation',
                 'sklearn.utils.sparsetools._graph_tools',
                 'sklearn.utils.lgamma',
                 'sklearn.utils.weight_vector']

datas = collect_data_files('sklearn')
```

I do not know if this part is necessary but I also created a hook-sklearn.py file that looks like this:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_submodules
hiddenimports = collect_submodules('sklearn')
```

In the cmd I used `pyinstaller test.py -F` to create one file.

Then it should work:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply Chris. I checked in the hooks folder and there's already a file in the hooks dir called hook-sklearn.metrics.cluster.py: 
`# Tested on Windows 7 64bit with scikit-learn 0.17 and Python 2.7
hiddenimports = ['sklearn.utils.sparsetools._graph_validation',
                 'sklearn.utils.sparsetools._graph_tools',
                 'sklearn.utils.lgamma',
                 'sklearn.utils.weight_vector']'`
I also added a print statement in this hook, which verifies that it's being called. It appears directly before the warnings now.

Comment: It worked! I did have hook files in place for the ones you mention above, but the problem was I only had the hiddenimports statements. Once I included the 'datas' line it worked as you outline. I'll also mention I ran pyinstaller in the onedir mode but I'll try it in single file mode too.  Edit: also I still get the warnings shown above even though it works- I guess they are just warnings and not errors? Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: @LukeWalsh I'm pretty sure the `Warning Hidden import ... not found ` is satisfied  in the hook-sklearn.py file. I am glad it worked for you. Let me know if you run into any other issues.

Comment: Where is the hooks folder located? I am not sure where to place these files. Thanks.

Comment: @schrodingerscat11 using Anaconda on windows: `C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks` or on a Mac: `/Users/user_name/opt/anaconda3/pkgs/pyinstaller-3.6-py38ha441bb4_5/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks` but you need to make sure the version are correct. Probably easiest to search your computer for the `pyinstaller` folder.