# Error on running exe build using Pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, py2exe

Following is the list of modules I am using:

```
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
from sklearn.cluster import MeanShift, estimate_bandwidth
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs
import re
import jellyfish
```

Exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_webagg.py", line 29, in <module>
    import tornado
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tornado'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 12, in <module>
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_webagg.py", line 31, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError("The WebAgg backend requires Tornado.")
```

Error on running the generated exe:

```
File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\isolve\iterative.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 714, in load_module
    module = loader.load_module(fullname)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
[22724] Failed to execute script main
```

I have tried the suggested solutions on git links but nothing seems to work. The script itself runs fine. Iam on Windows 10, Python 3.6

Comment: have you tried with cx_Freeze?

Comment: Yes, I tried but I believe I couldn't configure the setup.py properly and it gave me host of errors

Comment: try python -m pip install tornado and importing tornado.

Comment: New warnings : 
65756 WARNING: Hidden import "sklearn.utils.sparsetools._graph_validation" not found!
65757 WARNING: Hidden import "sklearn.utils.sparsetools._graph_tools" not found!

And new errors on running generated exe probably related to the warnings:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    from sklearn.cluster import MeanShift, estimate_bandwidth
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)

Comment: do you got multiple python interpreters installed?

Comment: I just have python 3.6

Comment: try copying python's dlls tcl and tck to the folder.

Comment: The error which I got now is :
 File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    from sklearn.cluster import MeanShift, estimate_bandwidth
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 134, in <module>
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module

Comment: I am finally able to run the exe. Thanks a lot for your comments. Though they did not answer my issue directly , but for sure helped me to search in right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to finally resolve the issue by following:

1. Installing and  install tornado and importing tornado as pointed by
       Diego Contreras in comments
2. Following the steps mentioned in the post [[How do you resolve 'hidden imports not found!' warnings in pyinstaller for scipy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49559770/how-do-you-resolve-hidden-imports-not-found-warnings-in-pyinstaller-for-scipy])

Make sure your Microsoft build tools are installed and the dll location is present in PATH(both x86 and x64). Restart the machine after editing PATH variables.