# scipy import error with pyinstaller

Tags: python, scipy, pyinstaller

I am trying to build a "One File" executable for my project with pyinstaller and a .spec file.  The content of the spec file is as follows:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['__main__.py'],
             pathex=['D:\\opt_frame'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=['scipy.special', 'scipy.special.comb'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='__main__',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='__main__')
```

I am getting the following error when I am trying to run the executable:

```
File "site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py", line 640, in <module>
  File "d:\opt_frame\.venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 714, in load_module
    module = loader.load_module(fullname)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

It fails when trying to import scipy.special even though I have added it to hiddenimports section.

My environment is as follows:

- Windows 10
- python 3.6.6
- pyinstaller 3.3.1
- scipy 1.1.0

Answer (score 3):

I had the **exact** same problem and I found a solution in another thread, ([How do you resolve 'hidden imports not found!' warnings in pyinstaller for scipy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49559770/how-do-you-resolve-hidden-imports-not-found-warnings-in-pyinstaller-for-scipy?rq=1))

I made the hook-scipy.py file that Chris's answer suggested with the exact same code:

```
    from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_submodules
    from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files
    hiddenimports = collect_submodules('scipy')

    datas = collect_data_files('scipy')
```

Worked like a charm! Hope this helps you as well.