# Pyinstaller cannot compile project with sklearn

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, compiler-errors, anaconda, pyinstaller

I'm trying to compile this simple python 3 (pyconda) machine learning project with sklearn and these imports (it's a simple Ridge regression predictor):

```
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
 
 
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
 
 
class covidUpdater:
    situazione = ""    
 
    def getCovidUpdate(self):
        url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pcm-dpc/COVID-19/master/dati-andamento-nazionale/dpc-covid19-ita-andamento-nazionale.csv"
        ds = pd.read_csv(url)
        return ds.tail(self.giorni)    
 
    def __init__(self):
        pass
 
 
    def setGiorni(self,giorni):
        self.giorni = giorni
        self.situazione = self.getCovidUpdate()        
 
    def getCampo(self,campo):
        return self.situazione[[campo]]
 
    def getMaxLength(self):
        ur1l = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pcm-dpc/COVID-19/master/dati-andamento-nazionale/dpc-covid19-ita-andamento-nazionale.csv"
        ds1 = pd.read_csv(ur1l)
        return len(ds1)
 
    def formatTable(self,campo):
        giorniPrediction = 1
        updater = covidUpdater()
        updater.setGiorni(self.giorni)
        updaterFuture = covidUpdater()
        updaterFuture.setGiorni(self.giorni+giorniPrediction)
        datiCampo = updater.getCampo(campo)
        datiCampoFuture = updaterFuture.getCampo(campo)
        campo_domani = str(campo) + "_domani"
        datiCampo[campo_domani] = datiCampoFuture.shift(-giorniPrediction)
        datiCampo = datiCampo.head(self.giorni-giorniPrediction)
        datiCampo["id"] = range(datiCampo.iloc[:, 0].size)
        return datiCampo
 
 
 
 
def main():
    campo = "nuovi_positivi"
    updater = covidUpdater()
    giorni = int(input("Inserisci numero giorni da usare come dataset> ") or updater.getMaxLength())
    updater.setGiorni(giorni)
    print("Giorni selezionati: ",giorni)
    df = updater.formatTable(campo)
 
    print("Imposto l'algoritmo di predizione")
    X = df.iloc[:, 0].values.reshape(-1,1)
    Y = df.iloc[:, 1].values.reshape(-1,1)
    regr = Ridge(alpha=1.0,normalize=False,tol=0.1,solver="lsqr")
 
    print("Avvio l'algoritmo di predizione")
    regr.fit(X,Y)
    Y_pred = regr.predict(X)
 
    print("-----------------------------------\n")
    print("Giorni in esame: "+ str(giorni)+"\n")
    print("Predizione di (" + str(date.today()) + ") : "+ str(regr.predict(np.array([Y[Y.size-1]])))+"\n")
    print("fattore R2: "+ str(regr.score(Y,Y_pred))+"\n")
    print("-----------------------------------"+"\n")
 
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

By using this command:

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --console --hidden-import "sklearn.linear_model.Ridge"  "PATH"
```

I have this log the final error is:

### Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\pyconda\lib\site-packages\auto_py_to_exe\packaging.py", line 131, in package
    run_pyinstaller()
  File "d:\pyconda\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 114, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "d:\pyconda\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 65, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "d:\pyconda\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 720, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "d:\pyconda\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 667, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp854ytoyk\covid2.spec", line 17, in <module>
    noarchive=False)
  File "d:\pyconda\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 242, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "d:\pyconda\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 160, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "d:\pyconda\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 419, in assemble
    self.graph.process_post_graph_hooks()
  File "d:\pyconda\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 365, in process_post_graph_hooks
    module_hook.post_graph()
  File "d:\pyconda\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 440, in post_graph
    self._load_hook_module()
  File "d:\pyconda\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 407, in _load_hook_module
    self.hook_module_name, self.hook_filename)
  File "d:\pyconda\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 588, in importlib_load_source
    return mod_loader.load_module()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 407, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 907, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 732, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 265, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 696, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "d:\pyconda\lib\site-packages\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\stdhooks\hook-zmq.py", line 21, in <module>
    hiddenimports = ['zmq.utils.garbage'] + collect_submodules('zmq.backend')
  File "d:\pyconda\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 595, in collect_submodules
    repr(pkg_dir), package))
  File "d:\pyconda\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 79, in exec_statement
    return __exec_python_cmd(cmd)
  File "d:\pyconda\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 68, in __exec_python_cmd
    txt = exec_python(*cmd, env=pp_env)
  File "d:\pyconda\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 521, in exec_python
    return exec_command(*cmdargs, **kwargs)
  File "d:\pyconda\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 316, in exec_command
    out = out.decode(encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8a in position 112: invalid start byte
```

Full log here: https://pastebin.com/XuBeLz3X

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start with the first error in the log:

```
3560572 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'sklearn.linear_model.Ridge'
3560576 ERROR: Hidden import 'sklearn.linear_model.Ridge' not found
```

Have you had a look at this thread with the Hidden import error? [How do you resolve 'hidden imports not found!' warnings in pyinstaller for scipy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49559770/how-do-you-resolve-hidden-imports-not-found-warnings-in-pyinstaller-for-scipy)

I think you need to adjust your hidden imports, so that 'sklearn.linear_model.Ridge' can be found.

And I just tried running your code in Google Colab (https://colab.research.google.com/) and it works there. Perhaps you can run your code there?

Comment: The code itself compiles, i was trying to develop a standalone to send to one of my friends. Is there an alternative than using pyinstaller to create a machine learning standalone?